# ERROR: "The selected device is incompatible" in Android HTC device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, ide

I am absolutly new in Android development (I am a Java EE developer) and this is the first time that I use **Android Studio**.

So I am finding some difficulties to run my HelloWorld application on my HTC One phone.

I have installed the driver of my phone on my Windows 8.1 system (it should be ok because I can correctly see my phone into the Windows Device Manager).

So I open my app into Android Studio and then click on the start button and then I can choose perform the application on my phone but then I obtain the following error message:

> **The selected device is incompatible**

Here a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Why? What is the problem? How is it possibile that my **Htc One** is incompatible with Android Studio? How can I fix this issue?

Another problem is that if I chose **Launch Emulator** instead my phisical phone I have not a virtual device. Is is something that have I to instal separatly or what?

Comment: Go to `Settings -> Developer Options -> Revoke USB debugging authorizations`. Select `OK` and disconnect your phone now. Reconnect it, run the app and you should get a popup on your phone asking for authorization. Provide the authorization and you should be okay to go now.

Comment: plug out and plug in again your mobile to your system and in your mobile screen you will see a dialog box check and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes reasons may be your device is not recognized by Android Studio.

For this to happen do the following:

1. Settings -> Developer Options -> Revoke USB debugging authorizations.
2. Select OK and disconnect your phone. Reconnect it, run the app and you should get a popup on your phone asking for authorization with title "Allow this Device..." . Tick the checkbox for future prefrence. and Select Ok.

Answer (score 1):

You have created the app with min SDK version 15 (as mentioned in the snapshot) but your device is working on a lower version of android. You can change the min SDK version from project properties or create a new application project with lower or equal version of android SDK than the android version installed on your device.

The version of SDK, you select, will work on any device having same or higher version of android OS installed.

Gingerbread (version 10) will work on ~90% of the devices.

Comment: very attentively, this seems to be the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `minSdkVersion` defined in the grade file of your project is higher than the api version of your phone. So you should change `minSdkVersion`.
You can only start a virtual device, if you have previously downloaded a system image and configured the device with AVD Manager.